# Java Optimal way saving directory paths

Tags: java, directory, directory-listing

What is the best way to save directory paths by keeping the ability of calling them fast?

As an example:

```
 - private static String Path1 = "C:\\b\\x";
 - private static String Path2 = "C:\\b\\xy";
 - private static String Path3 = "C:\\b\\xyz";
```

A call would look like:  `funccall(Path1+"\\app");`

My first approach was to make them static, but i have over 60 paths to save so it gets a little bit confusing.

Is it good practice to save them into an HashMap?

regards
Stefan

Comment: Anything that allows you to access them cleanly. You could use a property file to get them out of the code.

Comment: Yes, you could store them in a `HashMap` but then you would need a `List<String>` to represent each file / subdirectory in the given path as value.

Comment: If I have the stuff in a property file i have to read it out again? I shouldn't use to much prop files, the project already depends on 3 prop-files.